# gulp-connect and gulp-stubby-server communication

Tags: gulp, gulp-connect

I am facing issue while communicating between `gulp-connect` and `gulp-stubby-server`.

`gulp-connect` is running on port 3006 and stubby is running on port 8000 but somehow it's trying to connect to stubby on port 3006 only and I am getting 404 error. I have done proxy middleware configuration to redirect all request of path `/my-server` to stubby server but it seems to not working. What am I missing here?

> angular.js:12185 POST http://localhost:3006/my-server/services/getTestData 404 (Not Found)

```
var configuration = {
    myProxy: _.extend(url.parse('http://localhost:8000/my-server/'), {route: '/my-server'})

}
gulp.task('static', function () {
    connect.server({
        root: ['target'],
        port: 3006,
        livereload: false,
        middleware: function () {
            return [
                proxy(configuration.myProxy)
            ];
        }
    });
});

gulp.task('stubby', function (cb) {
    var options = {
        files: [
            'mocks/test/*.{json,yaml,js}'
        ],
        callback: function (server, options) {
            server.get(1, function (err, endpoint) {
                if (!err) {
                    console.log(endpoint);
                }
            });
        },
        stubs: 8000,
        tls: 8443,
        admin: 8010

    };
    stubby(options, cb);
});
```

**sample mock.json**

```
{
  "request" : {
    "url": "^/my-server/services/getTestData$",
    "method": "GET"
  },
  "response":{
    "status" : 200,
    "headers" :{
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    "latency" : 1000,
    "body" : "Some Test Data"
  }

}
```

**resource**

```
var testResource = function($resource , CONS){
    console.log('test resource');

    var requestURL = '/my-server/services/getTestData';
    return $resource(requestURL , {},{
        getTestData: {
            method: 'POST'
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the error log you posted:

> angular.js:12185 POST http://localhost:3006/my-server/services/getTestData 404 (Not Found)

That's a `POST` request, but you've only mocked `GET` requests in your **mock.json** file. You need to allow for both `POST` and `GET` requests:

```
{
  "request" : {
    "url": "^/my-server/services/getTestData$",
    "method": ["GET", "POST"]
  },
  "response":{
    "status" : 200,
    "headers" :{
      "Content-Type" : "application/json"
    },
    "latency" : 1000,
    "body" : "Some Test Data"
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I got '405 method not allowed error'. One more thing , why the port number in url is 3006? shouldn't it be 8000 because that's where my mock is running.

Comment: You shouldn't get a 405 error. I tested it with the code in your question. If it doesn't work, then the code that you're running isn't identical to the code in your question.

Comment: This code in question is same as my environment. I am not sure what is the issue. I would love to accept your answer but since it didn't resolve my issue , I have only upvoted. Thank you for helping me.